# How to evaluate if regexp match or string compare is faster

Tags: regex, perl

How can i evaluate which expression is faster:

```
grep($var eq $_, qw(abc ijk abcdef def))
```

OR

```
$var =~ /^abc|ijk|abcdef|def$/
```

**Edit**: Correcting the regular expression to:

`$var =~ /^(?:abc|ijk|abcdef|def)$/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure both the expressions are semantically equivalent (e.g. test against "qqqijkqqq").

Use [Benchmark](http://p3rl.org/Benchmark) to compare speed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


use Test::More;
use Benchmark qw{ cmpthese };

for my $var (qw(a abc ijk abcdef def qqqijkqqq)) {
    is_deeply(!!G($var), !!R($var), "same $var");
}
done_testing();

sub G {
    my $var = shift;
    grep $var eq $_, qw(abc ijk abcdef def)
}

sub R {
    my $var = shift;
    $var =~ /^(?:abc|ijk|abcdef|def)$/
}

cmpthese(-3,
         { grep  => 'G("abc")',
           regex => 'R("abc")',
         });
```

The output of the benchmark:

```
          Rate  grep regex
grep  631585/s    --  -23%
regex 824557/s   31%    --
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your regex is wrong. Place the piped words inside the `()` to make it correct.

```
^(?:abc|ijk|abcdef|def)$
 ^                    ^
```

Now come to the speed. I didn't find any documentation on this. So came up with my own piece of code to test it. Here it is:

```
my $var = "abc";

## block 1
my $x = time();
for(1..10000000){
    grep($var eq $_, qw(abc ijk abcdef def));
}
my $y = time();
print "grep: " . ($y- $x);

## block 2    
$x = time();
for(1..10000000){
    $var =~ /^(?:abc|ijk|abcdef|def)$/;
}
$y = time();
print "regex: " . ($y- $x);
```

And it came up with following output(values are in `seconds`) which shows regex is faster(specially in this particular case)!:

```
grep: 5
regex: 2
```